# Why does Windows 10 show issues after booting into Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, boot, usb

The situation I have is that I have Windows 10 installed on my PC on the SSD disk, with the bootloader also installed on the SSD, next to it I have a data HDD meant for Windows. Today I've created an Ubuntu 16.04 USB stick, it has a full installation on it, so not a Live USB or anything like it.

I'm experiencing the following issues when performancing the following sequence:

1. Boot into a completely fine Windows 10 environment
2. Insert my USB stick, change boot priority in the UEFI BIOS and boot into a completely fine Ubuntu 16.04 environment.
3. Remove my USB stick, change boot priority back again and boot into a messed up Windows 10 environment

Of course I power down my machine in between the steps, I do have Windows 10 Fast Startup enabled, but as far as I see there are no changes to my system between Windows 10 boots.

The issues I am experiencing are the following:

- Missing icons in my System Tray, the cause for this is a corrupt Icon Cache, I managed to fix this by following the steps in http://www.howtogeek.com/232779/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-icon-cache-in-windows-10/
- The clock of my system is one hour off, I managed to fix this by forcing Windows to resynchronize with its time server

Obviously it is annoying to have to do this every boot as I plan to switch between systems daily, what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, have you considered running Ubuntu as a Hyper-V virtual machine within Windows 10?  To be honest, I have been active within the Super User community for less than three months but I have already lost count of the numerous questions authored by people who experience problems when they try to dual-boot Windows 10 and Linux.  In stark contrast, I almost never hear about people having any type of issues running a Linux virtual machine using Windows 10 Hyper-V.

Comment: @Run5k Yes, but I absolutely need GPU support and the tool I'm running does not offer that inside a VM. With GPU support it gave a performance increase from 20 hours to 10 minutes for a certain operation.

Answer (score 0):

The clock issue is easily fixed: as installed, Ubuntu uses UTC (AKA GMT or prime meridian time), but [edit */etc/default/rcS* to make Ubuntu use your local time zone, or make a Registry change to force Windows to use UTC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot).

The issue with the icon cache is most likely from an existing hiberfil.sys. Be sure to turn off hibernate with the following command, run as Administrator:

> powercfg -h off

If you want to hibernate whiles staying in Windows, just do the converse with *on* as the parameter.

You may also need to turn off Fast Startup, which saves Windows state to disk. After rebooting successfully to both Windows and Ubuntu, though, I've had no issue with then re-enabling Fast Boot.